# Converting hundreds of HDF files into .tif in R

Tags: r, gis, rgdal, hdf

HDF to tif conversion using get_subdatasets in gdalUtils in R package is very slow process as i'm having 460 HDF files. Every conversion is taking  around 5 minutes. I want a fast alternative.

I converted a particulate sub-dataset of HDF4 files into tif format using gdalUtils package in R. I used get_subdatasets command. Every conversion took around 5 minutes and i need to convert 460 HDF files. It's taking too much time.

```
library(gdalUtils)
sds = get_subdatasets(hdffilepath)
# took around 5 minutes for a single file.
# can anyone suggest me a fast alternative?
```

Comment: how big are the files you are converting?

Comment: No guarantee of success but I'd try gdal_traslate http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/2.4.0/gdal-2.4.0.tar.gz .  It's written in c++ so likely to have less overhead then R version